# Is that possible to build an Equinox + Eclipse application without the GUI part?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I'm using the [rodin and eventb framework](http://www.event-b.org/), which use equinox and eclipse. We are now modifying it to support new features for my research team, and we want to get rid of the GUI part (mostly to be able to avoid writing gui code and to be able to launch heavy computation on remote servers). We succeed to have our own bundle with our code and which need only the following eclipse and equinox bundle (from eclipse version 3.7.1):

- org.eclipse.ant.runtime
- org.eclipse.core
- org.eclipse.core.contenttype
- org.eclipse.core.expressions
- org.eclipse.core.jobs
- org.eclipse.core.resources
- org.eclipse.equinox
- org.eclipse.osgi

and the rodin and eventb bundles:

- org.rodinp.core
- org.eventb.core
- org.eventb.ast

During startup of the osgi container, a directory workspace is created and some errors are reported in `.metadata/.log`, but it seems configuration error I could fix...

The question: is that a good idea to try to do this without the gui ? I'm afraid to spend a lot of time for discovering bug or impossibility to run the whole set due. Has anyone some experiences on such configuration ?

Comment: No experience with Rodin/eventb, but generally there shouldn't be a problem with a headless RCP. Its a good way to start with an RCP, because you can pretty easy add a UI at a later time if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need GUI why should you include it into your application? You can use Maven with [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) for headless build of Eclipse application.